# OpenMp warning: ignoring #pragma opm parallel

Tags: c++, openmp

I am getting this warning After I enter "g++ test1.c -fopenmp -Wall" with OpenMP directives on Windows:

`wtest1.c:6: warning: ignoring #pragma opm parallel [-Wunknown-pragmas]  #pragma opm parallel for private(x)`

OpenMp doesn't seem to beworking. Waht should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's `#pragma`**`omp`**, not `#pragma`**`opm`**